# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2024

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Solana Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://solana.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **February 13, 2024** to bring in 1 more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on February 13, users can [nominate themselves](https://solana.stackexchange.com/election/2). Users can also ask questions on Meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On February 20, if there are 2 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 2 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on Meta on February 28 (or March 6, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.

Comment: What happened to Joe C?

Comment: Joe C was removed as per [our inactivity policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338006/208518).

Comment: Thank you JNat!

Comment: I see that a local mod unsuccessfully tried to [unfreeze the main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/137725/2024/2/13) - perhaps some help is needed there. (At the same time, the room was silent for ages, so probably nobody won't really miss it.)

Comment: Unfroze it, @MartinSleziak ;)